# Just getting started with ubuntu and want to know how to access the full hard drive

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

So I just bought this laptop the other day; its a Dell Latitude e5500.
It has Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU P8400 @ 2.26GHz × 2; 2gb ram, 160gb hdd
Mobile Intel® GM45 Express Chipset. When I bought it, Windows 7 came with it.

After setting up Windows 7, the computer was running really slow. I thought that it might just be the ram, but when looking in the task manager I saw that the CPU was constantly running at damn near 100% the whole time. So I decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04.

So I used `unetbootin` to install Uubuntu, then did the full install. Once I had Ubuntu on the comp.

Now I saw the windows 7 partition on the desktop, and unmounted it; because I don't want windows 7 anymore and I didn't have anything on there that I wanted.

But now Ubuntu is telling me that I only have a 10gb hard drive when I should be seeing a 160gb hdd.

How can I find and access the full HDD so that I can utilize all of that space?

Comment: From what you are saying, it appears that you installed the ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a partition with 10GiB memory space. You could try installing `gparted` and looking into the hard drive memory structure. I think, the other partition which earlier had window's is not getting mounted. I hope it helps.

Comment: how would i go about installing gparted ? im still very new to linux/ubuntu. would it be sudo add -apt -gparted ?

Comment: @Bryan `sudo apt install gparted`

Answer (score -2):

You can install GParted 2 ways :

with a terminal :

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

or graphically :

- Open Ubuntu Software Center.
- Type "gparted" in the search bar.
- Click on the line were gparted in written.
- Click on the install button that appears on the right.

Comment: ok sorry responding back so late, running some other errands.

Comment: so i have downloaded gparted. but now im stuck on how to add the old windows partition to the ubuntu partition so that its just one partition so i can utilize the whole hdd. i have

Comment: sorry i keep hitting enter thinking the cursor will go down in the window here. i have formated the partition to ext4

Comment: first delete the windows partition, and then right click on the linux partition, and choose "resize/move"

Comment: ok, and then what do i do next ? it asks for free space preceding (mib); new size (mib), free space following (mib),  align to: next to each one of those selections is a menu. what should i do from there ? thank you very much for your help you guys !!! i really appreciate it.

Comment: i figured it out guys !!!! thank you very much !!